# Upload Image file to Http Server using post method in android

Tags: android, http

I need to upload image file to http server using post method.
My code is here

```
try {
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
        new FileInputStream(file), -1);
reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");

httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
//Do something with response...

} catch (Exception e) {
// show error
}
```

It's not working.Suggest me the right way.

Note : Server is IIS server.

Comment: `It's not working.` Possibly the most useless statement in software.  The wrong image is posted?  Your app crashes?  No image is posted?  The server crashes?  The sun stops shining?

Comment: I have uploaded a right image only. Application not crashed. At the time of uploading InputStreamEntity has the file data.But at server side it is file data is null. I thought my comments has the much details. If it possible suggest me useful information Simon.

Answer (score 0):

you can try  `reqEntity.setChunked(true);` Send in multiple parts if needed

for this your code should be

```
InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
        new FileInputStream(file), -1);
reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
reqEntity.setChunked(true);
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

but if your **file heavy in size** so you should use

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

File f = new File(file);
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(fileInputStream, f.length());

httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

if (responseEntity != null) {
  responseEntity.consumeContent();
}

httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also stucked at this point some days before and couldn't get anything working. I was using WCF rest service and spend 15-20 days in it. finally I changed my WCF to webservice and now I am able to upload image and call service very easily. I use SOAP object to get it called

```
private String RegisterUser(String[] parameter, String image) {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                OPERATION_NAME);

        request.addProperty("param1", parameter[0].toString());
        request.addProperty("param2", parameter[1].toString());
        request.addProperty("profilepic", image);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        Object response = null;

        try {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + OPERATION_NAME, envelope);
            response = envelope.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            response = exception.toString();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
```

I have converted my Image to string and then called to webservice and everything is very smooth.

You can try it if willing to use webservice. Hope this will help you

Regards,
Sourabh